# Как красиво вернуть переменную через return

Tags: java, android, listener

Допустим у меня есть метод с слушателем (для примера выбрал запрос к VK Api, он был под рукой):

```
private void getSubscribersInGroup() throws Exception {
        //Устанавливается пауза, чтобы код не выполнялся, пока
        //не будет получен ответ в слушатель
        isPause = true; 

        //Создаю запрос (указываю что мне нужно получить)
        final VKRequest request = VKApi.groups().getMembers(VKParameters.from(
                VKApiConst.GROUP_ID, groupId,
                VKApiConst.COUNT, 0));

        //Посылаю запрос и устанавливаю слушатель с методами
        request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                //Обрабатываю ответ и получаю его в ГЛОБАЛЬНУЮ переменную
                subscribersCount = getCountFromJSON(response.responseString);
                //Отключаю паузу, чтобы код продолжился
                isPause = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError e) {
                //По скольку это метод из API, я не могу выбрасывать Exception,
                //приходится прибегать к такому варианту
                isError = true;
                error = "error when requesting count: " + e.errorMessage;
                isPause = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
                //Аналогично предыдущему методу
                isError = true;
                error = "onAttemptFailed when requesting count: " +
                        "attemptNumber = " + attemptNumber +
                        "totalAttempts = " + totalAttempts;
                isPause = false;
            }
        });

        //Метод просто вызывает в бесконечном цикле "wait" на 100 миллисекунд,
        //с условием (isPause)
        waitResponseFromServer();
        //Если была ошибка — кидаю исключение
        if (isError) throw new Exception(error);
    }
```

Я хочу вернуть переменную `count` через `return`, а не использовать глобальную переменную. Методы слушателя имеют доступ только к `final` переменным метода, поэтому я не могу напрямую обращаться к ним. *Android Studio* предложила вариант сделать переменную `count` массивом — `final int[] count = new int[1];`, а потом работать с первым элементом массива. Как по мне, это немного не очевидный ход, который мне не сильно нравится. Есть еще варианты вернуть из метода переменную `subscribersCount` так, чтобы не использовать глобальную переменную?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас не получится вернуть переменную через return, так как запрос происходит асинхронно. Вы можете передавать в этот метод listener

```
private void getSubscribersInGroup(final OnSubscriptionListener listener)
```

где OnSubscriptionListener:

```
public interface OnSubscriptionListener {
    void onUpdateSubscribersCount(int subscribesCount);
}
```

и вызывать его внутри onComplete (VKResponse response)

```
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            //Обрабатываю ответ и получаю его в ГЛОБАЛЬНУЮ переменную
            int subscribersCount = getCountFromJSON(response.responseString);
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onUpdateSubscribersCount(subscribersCount);
            }

            //Отключаю паузу, чтобы код продолжился
            isPause = false;
        }
```

Не совсем понятно для каких целей вам ее нужно вернуть именно через return

Comment: Я пример с VK Api привел исключительно для примера, меня интересует именно возвращение через `return`, потому что часто сталкиваюсь с таким.

Comment: тут дело не в примере VK API. Если вы хотите вернуть значение из метода назовем его А, внутри которого будет выполнятся другой метод с callback'ом назовем его Б (т.е. выполняться асинхронно), и если вы хотите значение, которое вернет коллбэк метода Б вернуть  в return метода А, то это не возможно. Невозможно, потому что они выполняются асинхронно, т.е. пока вы дождетесь вызова коллбэка для метода Б, return метода А уже давно вызовется.